# JavaScript path doesn't load on Live Server extension (VS Code)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, liveserver

HTML and CSS files are working perfectly on my live server. But every time I lead to a .js script it will not be shown on my live server. If I try to load the .js file directly through the URL it shows "Cannot GET /line.js". I already tried out everything I've found on the internet but it's still not working. Here are the points I checked/did:

Installed Code Runner

Installed Node.js =  node.js system path done

Settings = Live Server Config = specified browser

"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome" on JSON settings

.js file is in a separate folder and accessed via `<script src="line.js"></script>` on index.html

Chrome is set as default browser on my system

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: ".js file is in a separate folder" OK. `<script src="line.js"></script>` — You forgot to include the folder in the path to it. You've explicitly said to look for the file in the **same** folder.

Answer (score 1):

If the js file is in a separate folder, you need to provide the exact route to the folder in the script tag, since in the current form it is trying to find the js file in the root directory. The script tag should look like this:

```
<script src="FOLDER_NAME/line.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that your javascript file is being loaded before the HTML page is rendered. You can try adding "defer" to your script tag like this:

`<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>`

Comment: A 404 error isn't going to go away if you wait a few milliseconds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).